# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi disconnect every 1-20 minutes

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (from 12.04) and my wifi keeps dropping out constantly between 1-20min. I have tried to search around and follow some advice found on forums (eg disabling N mode) but have had no luck. 
I'm fairly new to Ubuntu - please help.

wifi info can be found here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8285899/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this thread. (It might be a bit more advanced for you if you're only just starting out with Ubuntu)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2148130&page=2

Also you'll need to `sudo apt-get install git`

https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes